# CakePHP 4.x - bin/cake.php get deleted after running command

Tags: command, cakephp-4.x

In an cakephp app, I need to periodically retrieve data from an api. I also need the admin to be able to launch the update manually.

So I created a model accessing the data; this way I can use it in a controller and in the command/cronjob.

In the controller, no problem, it's running fine.

The problem is when I run the task in the bash : the bin/cake.php file get deleted and I can't do anything (bake, run task, etc).

Here's my code (simplified version on what's failling):

```
// IN Table/ApisTable.php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Http\Client;

class ApisTable extends Table{
    public function getUrl(){
        $http = new Client();
        $response = $http->get('http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/1');
        return $response->getStringBody();
    }
}




// IN Entity/Api.php

namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class Api extends Entity{

}



//IN Command/TestCommand.php

namespace App\Command;

use Cake\Command\Command;
use Cake\Console\Arguments;
use Cake\Console\ConsoleIo;

class TestCommand extends Command {

        public function execute(Arguments $a, ConsoleIo $io){
                $this->loadModel('Apis');
                $data = $this->Apis->getUrl();
                $io->out($data);
        }
}
```

The file is deleted when I run `bin/cake test`

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :

After trying few thing on another computer, I solved it. I'll let the subject here, if someone else need it.

It was my antivirus who placed the file in quarantine when reaching another url.